# Biblatex and apa style: reviewauthor undefined warning

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I get the warning,

```
Package biblatex warning: Macro 'reviewauthor' undefined
```

when running the following,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{elvis,
    author = "Elvis Presley",
    title = "Turn Me One More Time",
    publisher = "Jail House Books",
    year = 1963,
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is a citation \textcite{elvis}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When using, say `style=authoryear` there's no warning.

Now this doesn't seem to cause any untoward effects yet but I hate warnings since they have a habit of coming back and haunting you later.

Any ideas what this is about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning is harmless. The reasons why it is generated is because the `apa` style declares `\renewbibmacro{reviewauthor}` and the macro `reviewauthor` is not defined in the files loaded by the style.

However, the BibLaTeX manual, for `\renewbibmacro`, specifies

> Similar to `\newbibmacro` but redefines ⟨name⟩. In contrast to `\renewcommand`, `\renewbibmacro` issues a warning message if the macro is undefined, and automatically falls back to `\newbibmacro`.